# Tic Tac Toe Game, I want to offer the user the option to save game during gameplay(after first move). Here's a portion of my current code

Tags: python

> I am attempting to prompt the user the option to save the game, after the first move, during gameplay?
>   After the game is completed I want to prompt the user to reset the game(Y or N) then call the play game function(with a loop)?
>   However, I am unsure how to organize the code to accomplish these tasks. I am a beginner to python.

```
def play_game():

    game = True
    while game == True:
        game_choice = menu()
        if game_choice == 1:
            choice_one()
        elif game_choice ==2:
            player1VSai()
        elif game_choice ==3:
            save_and_exit()
        elif game_choice==4:
            load_game()

#After the game is completed I want to reset the game and call the play game function(with a loop).
       # reset_game()
      #  play_game()


def choice_one():
    # Display initial board
    display_board()


    while game_still_playing:
        # handle a single turn of a arbitrary player
        handle_turn(current_player)


        # check if win or tie
        check_if_game_over()

        # flip to other player
        alternate_player()


        # The game has ended
    if winner == 'X' or winner == 'O':
        print(winner + " won.")
    elif winner == None:
        print("Tie.")





# handle a single turn of a random player
def handle_turn(player):
    print(player + "'s turn.")
    position = input("Choose a position from 1 to 9: ")
    # I can index into position with int instead of string

    valid = False
    while not valid:

        while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"] or position ==0:
            position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")
            if position == 0:
                save_and_exit()
            pass
            # convert from string to int
        position = int(position) - 1

        if board[position] == '':
            valid = True
        else:
            print("Space filled. Go again.")

    # Board at position equals X
    board[position] = player

    display_board()
    print("Press 0 to save & exit game.")
            #then if? or loop? prompt user to save game?
```

Comment: since you've asked for 3 things, can you get any of them individually to work?

Comment: The save function works properly. But both the load function and reset function does not work properly.

Comment: Also Thank You, also I attached my entire code below.

Answer (score 0):

For saving code, your Game has things that you should save:

1. The state of the board, variable `player`
2. Whose turn it is, variable
       `board`

This means you would have to write a function that takes these 2 variables as input argument and writes the content to a file.

Comment: Below is what I have for the save function, also thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> @Remy this is what I have for the save function,
>   which I believe works properly as I've saved the data I need.

```
def save_and_exit():
    global current_player
    #save and end loop
    turn=current_player
    option = menu()

    file=open("HW3game.txt", "w")

    for x in board:
        file.write(x)
    file.write(turn)
    file.write(str(option))

    file.close()

    print("You have saved the game and exited")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

# functions
# board
# display board
# ask if you want to be x or O
# menu
# play game
# take input & alternate turns
# check win
# check rows
# check columns
# check diagonals
# check tie
# is board full


# ---- Global Variables -----


# Game Board
board = [''] * 9

# If game is still going
game_still_playing = True

# Who won? Or Tie?
winner = None

# Prompt user to choose X's or O's
letter = input("Choose a letter X or O: ").upper()
current_player = letter

# Input validation
while current_player not in ('x', 'o', 'X', 'O'):
    letter = input("Try again. Choose a letter X or O:").upper()
    current_player = letter
    if letter.upper() not in ('X', 'O'):
        print("Not an appropriate choice.")
    else:
        break

print("Player 1 will be ", current_player + "'s.\n")


def display_board():
    print(board[6], "\t|", board[7] + "  | " + board[8])
    print("--------------")
    print(board[3], "\t|", board[4] + "  | " + board[5])
    print("--------------")
    print(board[0], "\t|", board[1] + "  | " + board[2])

# ("1) Player 1 vs Player 2\n2) Player 1 vs AI\n3) Load Game\n0) Save & Exit")
# play tic tac toe
def play_game():


    begin = "Y"
    while begin == "Y":
        game_choice = menu()
        if game_choice == 1:
            choice_one()
        elif game_choice ==2:
            player1VSai()
        elif game_choice ==3:
            save_and_exit()
        elif game_choice==4:
            load_game()





def choice_one():
    # Display initial board
    display_board()


    while game_still_playing:
        # handle a single turn of a arbitrary player
        handle_turn(current_player)


        # check if win or tie
        check_if_game_over()

        # flip to other player
        alternate_player()


        # The game has ended
    if winner == 'X' or winner == 'O':
        print(winner + " won.")
        clear_board = reset_game()
        play_game()
    elif winner == None:
        print("Tie.")
        reset_game()
        play_game()




# handle a single turn of a random player
def handle_turn(player):
    print(player + "'s turn.")
    position = input("Choose a position from 1 to 9: ")
    # I can index into position with int instead of string

    valid = False
    while not valid:

        while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"] or position ==0:
            position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")
            if position == 0:
                save_and_exit()
            pass
            # convert from string to int
        position = int(position) - 1

        if board[position] == '':
            valid = True
        else:
            print("Space filled. Go again.")

    # Board at position equals X
    board[position] = player

    display_board()
    print("Press 0 to save & exit game.")
            #then if? or loop? prompt user to save game?

def check_if_game_over():
    # 3 in a row
    check_for_winner()
    # full board
    check_if_tie()


def check_for_winner():
    # Set up global variables
    global winner

    # check rows
    row_winner = check_rows()
    # check columns
    column_winner = check_columns()
    # check diagonals
    diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()

    if row_winner:
        winner = row_winner
        print("There was a ROW win!")
    elif column_winner:
        winner = column_winner
        print("There was a COLUMN win!")
    elif diagonal_winner:
        winner = diagonal_winner
        print("There was a DIAGONAL win!")
    else:
        winner = None


def check_rows():
    # Set up global variables
    global game_still_playing

    # check rows for all the same values & is not an empty ''
    row_1 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != ''
    row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != ''
    row_3 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != ''

    # if any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
    if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
        game_still_playing = False
    # Return the winner (X or O)
    if row_1:
        return board[6]
    elif row_2:
        return board[3]
    elif row_3:
        return board[0]

    # return X or O if winner
    # then flag game still playing to false to end loop


def check_columns():
    # Set up global variables
    global game_still_playing

    # check columns for all the same values & is not an empty ''
    column_1 = board[6] == board[3] == board[0] != ''
    column_2 = board[7] == board[4] == board[1] != ''
    column_3 = board[8] == board[5] == board[2] != ''

    # if any column does have a match, flag that there is a win
    if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
        game_still_playing = False
    # Return the winner (X or O)
    if column_1:
        return board[6]
    elif column_2:
        return board[7]
    elif column_3:
        return board[8]

    # return X or O if winner
    # then flag game still playing to false to end loop


def check_diagonals():
    # Set up global variables
    global game_still_playing

    # check columns for all the same values & is not an empty ''
    diagonal_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != ''
    diagonal_2 = board[6] == board[4] == board[2] != ''

    # if any row does have a match, flag that there is a win
    if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
        game_still_playing = False
    # Return the winner (X or O)
    if diagonal_1:
        return board[0]
    elif diagonal_2:
        return board[6]

    # return X or O if winner
    # then flag game still playing to false to end loop


def check_if_tie():
    # declare global variable
    global game_still_playing

    # check if board full
    if '' not in board:
        game_still_playing = False
    return


def alternate_player():
    global current_player

    # if current player is == to X then change it to O
    if current_player == "X":
        current_player = 'O'
    # if current player is == to O then change it to X
    elif current_player == "O":
        current_player = 'X'


def player1VSai():

    #random number

    return


def save_and_exit():
    global current_player
    #save and end loop
    turn=current_player
    option = menu()

    file=open("HW3game.txt", "w")

    for x in board:
        file.write(x)
    file.write(turn)
    file.write(str(option))

    file.close()

    print("You have saved the game and exited")
    return


def menu():
    print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe")

    print("1) Player 1 vs Player 2\n2) Player 1 vs AI\n3) Save & Exit\n4) Load Game")
    game_choice = int(input("Choose an option, 0-4: "))
    #
    return game_choice


def load_game():
    #setup global
    global current_player

    file = open("HW3game.txt", "r")

    for i in range(0,8):
        board[i]=file.read(1)
    current_player=file.read(1)
    #current choice of game.
    game_choice=int(file.read(1))


    file.close()
    print("You have called the load function.")

    return


def reset_game():
    global board
    #erase contents in current board
    #replay game
    clear_board = board.clear()
    return clear_board





play_game()
```